# Common Lisp: Passing a lambda generated by a macro to remove-if-not results in error

Tags: common-lisp

I was following along with the first example project from the book [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html) when I encountered an error in the final product provided by the book.

The project is a basic database that stores information about cds. It supports a select and an update statement to be used along with a where macro.

I have tested the code using the clisp and sbcl compilers and the same error occurs for both.

Here is the code:

```
(defvar *db*)

(defun make-cd (title artist rating ripped)
  (list :title title :artist artist :rating rating :ripped ripped))

(defun add-record (cd) (push cd *db*))

(defun dump-db ()
  (format t "~{~{~a:~10t~a~%~}~%~}" *db*))

(defun prompt-read (prompt)
  (format *query-io* "~a: " prompt)
  (force-output *query-io*)
  (read-line *query-io*))

(defun prompt-for-cd ()
  (make-cd
   (prompt-read "Title")
   (prompt-read "Artist")
   (or (parse-integer (prompt-read "Rating") :junk-allowed t) 0)
   (y-or-n-p "Ripped [y/n]: ")))

(defun add-cds ()
  (loop (add-record (prompt-for-cd))
    (if (not (y-or-n-p "Another? [y/n]: ")) (return))))

(defun save-db (filename)
  (with-open-file (out filename
               :direction :output
               :if-exists :supersede)
    (with-standard-io-syntax
      (print *db* out))))

(defun load-db (filename)
  (with-open-file (in filename)
    (with-standard-io-syntax
      (setf *db* (read in)))))

(defun select (selector-fn)
  (remove-if-not selector-fn *db*))

(defun make-comparison-expr (field value)
  `(equal (getf cd ,field) ,value))

(defun make-comparisons-list (fields)
  (loop while fields
    collecting (make-comparison-expr (pop fields) (pop fields))))

(defun where (&rest clauses)
  `#'(lambda (cd) (and ,@(make-comparisons-list clauses))))

(defun update (selector-fn &key title artist rating (ripped nil ripped-p))
  (setf *db*
    (mapcar
     #'(lambda (cd)
         (when (funcall selector-fn cd)
           (if title (setf (getf cd :title) title))
           (if artist (setf (getf cd :artist) artist))
           (if rating (setf (getf cd :rating) rating))
           (if ripped-p (setf (getf cd :ripped) ripped)))
         cd)
     *db*)))

(defun delete-rows (selector-fn)
  (setf *db* (remove-if selector-fn *db*)))
```

Here is the call that produces the error:

```
(select (where :artist "Dixie Chicks"))
```

Basically what's going on in this call is the following. The where macro gives a lambda expression that takes in a cd and acts a predicate to determine whether the cd has certain values for certain fields.

In this specific call the where macro expands to:

```
#'(lambda (cd) (and (equal (getf cd :artist) "Dixie Chicks")))
```

Here is what *db* is currently defined as:

```
((:TITLE "Fly" :ARTIST "Dixie Chicks" :RATING 7 :RIPPED T)
 (:TITLE "Home" :ARTIST "Dixie Chicks" :RATING 9 :RIPPED T)
 (:TITLE "Lyle Lovett" :ARTIST "Lyle Lovett" :RATING 9 :RIPPED T)
 (:TITLE "Give Us a Break" :ARTIST "Limpopo" :RATING 10 :RIPPED T)
 (:TITLE "Rockin' the Suburbs" :ARTIST "Ben Folds" :RATING 6 :RIPPED T)
 (:TITLE "Naive" :ARTIST "The Kooks" :RATING 6 :RIPPED T)
 (:TITLE "It's the end of the world as we know it" :ARTIST "REM" :RATING 6
  :RIPPED T)
 (:TITLE "We Walk" :ARTIST "REM" :RATING 8 :RIPPED T))
```

Here is the error produced by the call above:

```
The value
  #'(LAMBDA (CD) (AND (EQUAL (GETF CD :ARTIST) "Dixie Chicks")))
is not of type
  (OR FUNCTION SYMBOL)
when binding SB-IMPL::PREDICATE
   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

Here are the expected results to the call above:

```
((:TITLE "Fly" :ARTIST "Dixie Chicks" :RATING 7 :RIPPED T)
 (:TITLE "Home" :ARTIST "Dixie Chicks" :RATING 9 :RIPPED T))
```

I have spent a significant amount of time reviewing this code before asking for help, but due to my very primitive knowledge of Common Lisp I can't seem to find the culprit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `where` should be a `defmacro`, not `defun` (don't forget to re-compile all users of `where` after the change).

Comment: @sds Thank you so much. I swear I was staring at this for like 2 hours. oops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed one crucial bit:

> Now you just need to wrap up the list returned by `make-comparison-list` in an `AND` and an anonymous function, which you can do in the `where` macro itself. Using a back quote to make a template that you fill in by interpolating the value of `make-comparisons-list`, it's trivial.
>
> ```
> (defmacro where (&rest clauses)
>   `#'(lambda (cd) (and ,@(make-comparisons-list clauses))))
> ```

In this version `where` is a macro, not a function; i.e. you need to define it using `defmacro`, not `defun`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is easy to find. If you know where to look. ;-)

The error says that `#'(LAMBDA (CD) (AND (EQUAL (GETF CD :ARTIST) "Dixie Chicks")))` is not a function or a symbol.

What is it? It is a list.

```
CL-USER 9 > '#'(LAMBDA (CD) (AND (EQUAL (GETF CD :ARTIST) "Dixie Chicks")))
(FUNCTION (LAMBDA (CD) (AND (EQUAL (GETF CD :ARTIST) "Dixie Chicks"))))

CL-USER 10 > (type-of *)
CONS
```

But a `cons` is not a function object or a symbol.

So then you *only* need find why you got this list and not a function object. You can then see that `where` returns the list. If `where` would be a macro, it would create this list as source, which then gets evaluated to a function object.

Comment: Now this is a good "teach them to fish" answer! SO needs a "meta-answer" check mark.